# Given a sorted array with a few numbers in between reversed. How to sort it?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

I am actually trying to solve a problem where I have an array which is sorted but a few numbers are reversed . For example :  `1 2 3 4 9 8 7 11 12 14` is the array.

Now , my first thought was applying a `Binary Search` algorithm to find a `PEAK ( a[i]>a[i+1] && a[i]>a[i-1])`

However , I feel it might not always give the correct result. Moreover it might not be efficient since the list is almost sorted.

Next impression : Applying `Insertion Sort` since the list is sorted and insertion sort gives best performance in such case IF I am not wrong.

So can anyone suggest better solutions or whether my solutions are correct or not? Efficient of In-efficient?

P.S - This is NOT homework !

UPDATE : Insertion Sort (O(n) in this case) or Linear Scan to find the subsequence and then reversing it (O(n)) again. Is there any chance if we could optimize it? Or probably do in O(logn) ?

Comment: Find the beginning and end of the reversed run(s) and revert it back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search linearly for the first inversion (i.e. `a[i+1] < a[i]`), call its index `inv1`. Continue until inversions stop, call the last index `inv2`. Reverse the array between `inv1` and `inv2`, inclusive.

In your example, `inv1` is 4, and `inv2` is 6; array elements are numbered from zero.

The algorithm is linear in the number of entries in the original.

Comment: Nice , So that would be O(n+d) ? d is the no. of inversions?

Comment: @sTEAK. It's `O(n)`, because `d` is `O(n)` as well, and `O(2n)` is the same as `O(n)` :)

Comment: Yeah definitely that is correct. Can we do it in O(logn) ? If such a solution exists?

Comment: @sTEAK. I think this is unlikely to find an `O(log N)` algorithm, because I can't think of an algorithm to find an inversion by chopping the sorted list in several parts.

Comment: BTW: thanks for accepting this "answer" while I was hacking at it.

Comment: @wildplasser You can share your answer too please. Besides , I can still upvote you.

Comment: it is obviously not possible to do better than O(N). there could be just 2 neighboring elements swapped. Good luck finding them without a linear search. BTW: the question does not say that the numbers are distinct - this is a good place for a bug, as evidenced by @wildplasser 's solution :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're sure that the list is sorted except for an embedded subsequence that is reversed, I suggest that you do a simple scan, detect the start of the reversed subsequence (by finding the first counter-directional change), scan to the end of the subsequence (where the changes resume the correct direction) and reverse the subsequence. This should also work for multiple subsequences provided they do not overlap. The complexity should be O(n).

Comment: Could you give an example for multiple subsequences so that I can make it clear?

Answer (score 1):

Note: there should be an extra decision whether to cut between {4,9}, or between {9,8}. (I just add one ;-)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[] = {1,2,3,4,9,8,7,11,12,14};

unsigned findrev(int *arr, unsigned len, unsigned *ppos);
void revrev(int *arr, unsigned len);

unsigned findrev(int *arr, unsigned len, unsigned *ppos)
{
unsigned zlen,pos;

for(zlen=pos=0; pos < len-1; pos++ ) {
        if (arr[pos+1] < arr[pos]) zlen++;
        else if (zlen) break;
        }
if (zlen) *ppos = pos - zlen++;

return zlen;
}

void revrev(int *arr, unsigned len)
{
unsigned pos;
for (pos = 0; pos < --len; pos++) {
        int tmp;
        tmp = arr[pos];
        arr[pos] = arr[len] ;
        arr[len] = tmp;
        }
}

int main(void)
{
unsigned start,len;

len = findrev(array, 10, &start);
printf("Start=%u Len=%u\n", start, len);
revrev(array+start, len);

for (start=0; start < 10; start++) {
        printf(" %d", array[start] );
        }
printf("\n"  );

return 0;
}
```

NOTE: the length of the reversed run could also be found by a binary-search for the first value larger (or equal) than the first element of the reversed sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Timsort is quite good at sorting mostly-already-sorted arrays - on top of that, it does an in-place mergesort by using two different mergesteps depending on which will work better.  I'm told it's found in the python and java standard libraries, perhaps others.  You still probably shouldn't use it inside a loop though - inside a loop you're better off with a treap (for good average speed) or red-black tree (for low standard deviation speed).

Answer (score 0):

I think linear solution [O(n)] is the best possible solution since in a list of n numbers, if n/2 numbers are reverse sorted as in example below we will have to invert n/2 numbers which gives complexity of O(n).

Also even in this case for a similar sequence, I think insertion sort will be O (n^2) and not O (n) in worst case.

Example: Consider an array with distribution below and we attempt to use insertion sort,

n/4 sorted numbers | n2 reverse sorted numbers | n/4 sorted numbers

For the n/2 reverse sorted numbers the sorting complexity will be O(n^2).